# Flow typing reducer produces no errors

Tags: reactjs, redux, flowtype

I'm new to flowtypes and want to ask for help typing this reducer.

```
// @flow

type State = {
  [id: string]: boolean
};

type Action = { type: 'SET_ID', id: number, someValue: string };

function reducer(state: State, action: Action): State {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_ID':
      const { id, someValue } = action;
      return { [id]: someValue };
    default:
      (action: empty);
      return state;
  }
}
```

I'm passing action with id as a number and someValue as a string, but state id should be string and someValue should be boolean. Flow produces 0 errors. Any ideas ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've been using flow for a little while, not a pro at it yet, but I think I might be able to help out. What I'm doing below is while ID is a variable, I don't think it needs to be assigned a key - its just a string. Its only assigned a variable because you are passing it into a function and using it - so all it ever needs to be is a string. This way if you pass it a number, it should now hopefully throw an error so you can decide if you want to convert the number into a string first, or change the initial item to be a number first instead of a string in the state type.

Then someValue is the value of the key(string), and it should also be a string and not a boolean.

```
type State = {
  [string]: string
};

type Action = { type: 'SET_ID', id: number, someValue: string };

function reducer(state: State, action: Action): State {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_ID':
      const { id, someValue } = action;
      return { [id.toString()]: someValue };
    default:
      (action: empty);
      return state;
  }
}
```

And an example of the returned data from the reducer might be this:

```
{'1231413413324': 'my new value from the reducer'}
```

Comment: Thanks for help, yeah I declared wrong types on purpose to check if flow gives me errors if I pass wrong types, but it does not. Tried your example on flow repl, and removing toString() on id should throw error that id should be string, but it does not. Found this issue on flow github https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2928, seems it's a bug(?). Not sure what to do now

Comment: I’ll have to check my project when I get back to double check that it throws an error. But I think in the docs it specifically says that you don’t need to specify the ID as a key when creating a key/value pair. I’ll see if I can find a link

Comment: Yeah ok, thanks, almost all of my reducers are with computed keys, so I can't type them. About naming the key, double checked the docs, you are right, it's optional :).

Comment: So I checked my reducer - and yea changing it from a string to a number didn't seem to throw any errors lol :(

Comment: Thanks for checking! Seems like flow is kinda useless in this situation then. ;/